# How can I do a dot product between a matrix and a vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector, valarray, inner-product

There are a function called `inner_product`, but I failed miserably in use that. I'll need to use this function several times for different matrices and vectors. Bellow my current code:

```
std::vector<vector<int>> matrix_a = {{0, 0},
                                     {0, 1},
                                     {1, 0},
                                     {1, 1}};
std::vector<float> vector_b = {0.5, 0.8};

dot_produt(matrix_a, vettor_b);
```

```
float dot_produt(vector<vector<int>> e, vector<float> p){
    return std::inner_product(std::begin(e), std::end(e), std::begin(p), 0.0);
}
```

The process is like:

```
(0.5 * 0) + (0.8 * 0) + (0.5 * 0) + (0.8 * 1)... ...
```

Expected output:

```
2.6
```

Error:

```
no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'std::vector<int>' and 'float')
__init = __init + (*__first1 * *__first2);
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why you expect this to work as-is. `vector<int>`s and `float`s aren't something you can arithmetically compare?

Comment: I was under the impression that the dot product is between two vectors. You'd use the dot product on rows and columns of a matrix, but not on the whole thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use pointers to begin and end of a vector of vectors, `inner_product` requires pointers to beginning and end of a vector.

Also, vectors have their own iterators, you can use them instead of `std::begin` and `std::end`.

[**Live demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LUDuI8BovEcGVETJ)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

//passing vectors by reference avoids unnecessary copies
double dot_produt(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &e, const std::vector<float> &p)
{
    double result = 0;
    for (auto& v : e) //range based loop
        result += std::inner_product(v.begin(), v.end(), p.begin(), 0.0);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix_a = {{0, 0},
                                              {0, 1},
                                              {1, 0},
                                              {1, 1}};
    std::vector<float> vector_b = {0.5, 0.8};

    std::cout << dot_produt(matrix_a, vector_b); //test print
}
```

Output:

```
2.6
```

Comment: An suggestion for https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/bvh-loader/issues/1 
i need 3x3 dot 3x3